# Turning pants inside-out (or backwards) while tied together

Tags: geometry, gt.geometric-topology, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

An entertaining topological party trick that I have seen performed is to turn your pants inside-out while having your feet tied together by a piece of string.  For a demonstration, check out this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O70156EDGuY).

I have heard some testimonial evidence that it is also possible to turn your pants *backwards*, again with the constraint of having your feet tied together.  This second claim seems pretty dubious to me.

**Question.** Is it indeed possible to turn your pants backwards, while having your feet tied together by a piece of string?  A set of instructions or a video demonstration would suffice for a yes answer.  A precise mathematical formulation of the problem together with a proof of impossibility would suffice for a no answer.

Comment: To avoid seeing something I might rather not: is that video _American_ or _British_?

Comment: It's perfectly decent.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think that the answer is no, by consideration of [linking numbers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number)
First simplify the human body plus cord joining the ankles to a circle, and 
assign it an orientation. Also assign an orientation to each pant cuff.
This can be done, e.g., so that each cuff has linking number +1 with the
"body" (in which case the two cuffs are oppositely oriented).

Now suppose that there is an isotopy of the pants that turns them backwards.
This means the left cuff is now on the right ankle and vice versa. But this
also reverses the linking numbers, which is impossible.

Comment: You're welcome, Tony. Thanks for asking such an irresistible question!

Comment: Neat, that simplification (with the cuffs connected at a point or line segment) also gets me to see why the inside-out procedure works. Of course I'm tempted to say "rotate the cuffs around the circle" (ha), but in fact you mostly just have to pass one cuff through the other at the bottom of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Go to: http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-769665253207419103#